# SQL Query to create Match causing duplicates unable to avoid

Tags: sql, duplicates, unique

I'm creating SQL Query to match from a staging table to a Dynamics GP Table.  The query I've created works for 90% of what I need except for when the Item Number and Line # are the same.  There are unique values on the lines such as LNITMSEQ and BoeingInvNmbr but I'm still unable to obtain 2 rows vs 4 rows, 2 which are duplicates. The Line # in one of the tables is X.X and I had to create a PATINDEX to remove the .X for the join to the PoLineNmbr.

I've tried DISTINCT, GROUP BY, using a CTE, different joins, etc. Without the expected result.

```
SELECT A.SOPNUMBE
    ,A.SOPTYPE
    ,A.CUSTNMBR
    ,B.BoeingPONmbr
    ,A.CSTPONBR
    ,D.ITEMNMBR
    ,B.PartNmbr
    ,D.QUANTITY AS GPQTY
    ,D.QTYTOINV
    ,D.QTYFULFI
    ,B.Quantity AS BQTY
    ,b.BoeingInvoiceNmbr
    ,B.InvGrossAmt
    ,D.XTNDPRCE
    ,D.LNITMSEQ
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY A.SOPNUMBE ASC
        ) AS SOP_Rank
FROM ZSWIN..SOP10100 A
LEFT JOIN Integration..BoeingInvoices B ON A.CSTPONBR = B.BoeingPONmbr
LEFT JOIN ZSWIN.dbo.adv_SalesTransactionEntry_CPO C ON A.MSTRNUMB = C.MSTRNUMB
    AND SUBSTRING([Line #], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [Line #]), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', [Line #] + 't') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [Line #]) + 1) = B.POLineNmbr -- altered line# to remove .X
LEFT JOIN ZSWIN..SOP10200 D ON C.LNITMSEQ = D.LNITMSEQ
    AND A.SOPNUMBE = D.SOPNUMBE
WHERE A.SOPTYPE = 2
    AND D.QTYTOINV = D.QTYFULFI
    AND D.QTYTOINV = B.Quantity
    AND A.SOPNUMBE NOT IN (
        SELECT SOPNUMBE
        FROM GPBoeingMatch
        )
    AND b.BoeingPONmbr = '1561870' 


Expected Results:
DS-19027  2  BOEING  1561870  1561870  895-00008-0400  895-00008-0400  8  8  8  8  0009294850  632.00  632.00000  16384  1
DS-19027  2  BOEING  1561870  1561870  895-00008-0400  895-00008-0400  8  8  8  8  0009453604  632.00  632.00000  32768  1 

Actual Results:
DS-19027  2  BOEING  1561870  1561870  895-00008-0400  895-00008-0400  8  8  8  8  0009294850  632.00  632.00000  16384  1
DS-19027  2  BOEING  1561870  1561870  895-00008-0400  895-00008-0400  8  8  8  8  0009453604  632.00  632.00000  32768  1
DS-19027  2  BOEING  1561870  1561870  895-00008-0400  895-00008-0400  8  8  8  8  0009294850  632.00  632.00000  16384  1
DS-19027  2  BOEING  1561870  1561870  895-00008-0400  895-00008-0400  8  8  8  8  0009453604  632.00  632.00000  32768  1
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data ? the `DISTINCT` should be work.

Comment: distinct is the only solution!!!!

Comment: @D-Shih Sample data of what is in all three tables? Such as the Insert/Values to each for this specific example...

Comment: Any other suggestions!?